# How to convert input from user to UCS2 in angular 7 and Send Msg through Usb Gsm Modem)

Tags: angular, serial-port, sms, electron, ucs2

I have an angular 7 app which get input (phone number and message) from user to send sms using electron serialport.

I want to encode phone number and message in UCS2. How can i convert it in angular 7.

I am not able to find any guide about converting to UCS2
I have tried 
https://maketips.net/tip/239/convert-to-ucs2-and-from-ucs2-in-javascript

But I am not able to include it properly as i am newbee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I tried to used a library 
https://github.com/emilsedgh/modem

and it worked well. So i didn't need to do anything (convert to ucs2) manually.

```
let isElectron: boolean = window && window['process'] &&  window['process'].type;
if(isElectron){
    modem.open("COM7",function(){
        console.log('modem opened');
        modem.sms({
            receiver:"00923325200***",
            text:"abc i am a msg",
            encoding:'16bit'
        }, function(err, sent_ids) {
            console.log('>>', arguments);
            if(err)
                console.log('Error sending sms:', err);
            else
                console.log('Message sent successfully, here are reference ids:', sent_ids.join(','));
                modem.close();
        });
    });
}
```